# Javascript text - can't make it listed

Tags: javascript, text, html-lists

soooo i have this function that prints one of 5 random texts ON an image (in my case, a notepad, like writing on it.)

```
function getatext()
{
   var whichtext=get_random();

    var text=new Array(5)
     text[0]="text0";
     text[1]="text1";
     text[2]="text2";   
     text[3]="text3";
     text[4]="text4";

     document.getElementById("notepad").innerHTML +=
             '<p class="notepad">'+(text[whichtext])+'</p>';
```

Thing is, every time i have text printed, it is printed on top of another, instead of like a new entry, and pushing the others down the list.

I tried `<li>` tags but most examples and tuts i can stumble upon use them in simple html pages, not in javascript text writes which appear somewhat more difficult (at least to me).

Using `'<p class="notepad">'+'<li>'+(text[whichtext])+'</li>'+'</p>';` got me the list appear, though it is not printed ON the image, but way off. I guess it completely ignores the `<p>` tag this way?

I even tried creating a `ul.notepad` inside my .css in case it mattered.. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** included from .css `.notepad`, `p.notepad` and `<content>` where all this is taking place:

```
#content {
    border-left:1px solid #000;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
    background:#ffffff;
    margin-left: 24.9%;
    width:75%;
    min-height:0;
    position:relative;  

.notepad {
        position: relative;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;  
        background-attachment:fixed; 
        width: 300px;
}

p.notepad {
    font-family:"Lucida Handwriting";
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px; 
    left: 65px;   
}
```

**EDIT 2:** after inspecting the problem some more, I've found out that `position: absolute;` inside my p.notepad is probably causing all this. A random text is printed for the first time, then when the time for the second text to be printed comes, it takes the same coords from p.notepad and that is why it prints it ontop of the 1st text. But having the position: absolute is important, otherwise the text it isn't printed ON my notepad image..

Comment: Have you tried floating a div (with absolute positioning) above the image? That would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a CSS issue, not an HTML issue. The formatting of your HTML is likely overlapping. It is difficult without seeing the CSS.

Here is an example of basically what you are doing, but working:

http://jsbin.com/abemiv

Use:
http://jsbin.com/abemiv/edit

to edit the source

Comment: the demo works alright, but adjusting it in my code it keeps printing the random texts in the same line.. that's why I edited and shared .notepad p.notepad and content :) Also, removing position: absolute; from p.notepad gets the text printed like in the demo, though it's not even in the notepad area anymore, and that's the point. Maybe I have to use display: block; somewhere like I see in the demo?

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is you have absolute positioning on the notepad class.

Try this CSS:

```
.notepad {
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: .notepad was position:relative already.. just for fun i changed it into :absolute and the notepad image messed up the <footer> and the page generally :P

Answer (score 0):

No need for the ul/li approach, the `<p>` `</p>` you have will suffice.  I agree on the likely culprit as css - can you post your css?